# Elasticsearch Terms Aggregation: Filter fields by pattern

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of indexed documents that contain some fields that are suffixed with, say, '-aggregation'.

I would like to build terms aggregations for these fields only, with a pattern or something. Some script would be fine for me, too.

Something that would look like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "facets": {
            "terms": {
                "(patter|regexp|something)": ".+-aggregation"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is that even possible?

For performance reasons I would prefer to filter the fields upfront.

The Elasticsearch version doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify filters to aggregations. See reference [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html).

A sample query may look like

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "facets": {
      "filter": {
        "prefix": {
          "color": "b"
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can specify any kind of filters and be aware about the performance considerations on using wildcards.

Comment: But I don't want to filter the values. I want to filter the keys. In your example I would still need to know the concrete name of the key, right?

Comment: For aggregations I think you have to specify exact field names.